# Android PreferenceFragment - Enable/Disable Receiver on Preference Change (Context issues, etc)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, android-context

I am in the process of integrating SharedPreferences into my App code..
I've chosen to use the `Preferences API`, along with a `PreferenceFragment`.
Unfortunately I'm having a bit of trouble referencing '`context`' from within the `Fragment`, etc..
I also can't quite figure out how to go about writing the code inside the ChangeListener.

The Settings/Preferences screen looks perfect, but I'm having issues making changes to the way my App behaves, based upon the User changing the preference.

**Here is an example..**
My goal is to Enable/Disable a BroadcastReceiver, when the User changes the Preference:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    public static final String PREF_GPS_STATE_LISTENER = "pref_gpsStateListener";

    private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener preferenceChangeListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate (@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        final SharedPreferences getPrefs = 
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getActivity());

        preferenceChangeListener = 
            new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged
                (SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

                if (key.equals(PREF_GPS_STATE_LISTENER)) {

                    if (getPrefs.getBoolean(PREF_GPS_STATE_LISTENER)) {

                        context().getApplicationContext()
                        .getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting
                            (component, 
                                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 
                                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Here are the three issues I'm having:

**(1) -** I can't seem to figure out how to correctly reference the 'context' (in the beginning of the code used to enable the BroadcastReceiver).

**(2) -** How do I go about correctly referencing the 'component' variable (within the same line of code as the above question)?

**(3) -** I don't think I've written the `if` statement correctly, and could use help correcting it.

Any help is much appreciated! I very much need some assistance fixing this.
Thanks :)

Comment: you can when the broadcast is received you can check if its is enabled or not in shared preferences. I see you have already made your prefs key public constant so you can easily check from shared preferences in any place within your app like `if sharedPrefs.getBoolean(PREF_GPS_STATE_LISTENER){// run broadcast code}`

Comment: and to get default shared preferences which are being used by `PrefrencesFragment` you can use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`

Comment: The idea of determining preference status within the `BroadcastReceiver` itself DID cross my mind - however, I assume it would be more efficient and less resource-intensive if I were to enable/disable the `BroadcastReceiver` directly from within the `onSharedPreferenceChanged` method, instead of having the `BroadcastReceiver` be receiving at ALL times even when it should be disabled, which seems somewhat counter-productive in terms of best practice.. Don't you agree? On that note, IS there a way to enable/disable the `BroadcastReceiver` from within `onSharedPreferenceChanged`, for efficiency??

Comment: before registering broadcast you can  put check for this condition. also you can sendBroadcast when preferences changed. there can be many possible solutions

Comment: also you can remove listening one time you checked and it is disabled so it will not be running

Comment: The `BroadcastListener` is to detect when the Location/GPS Setting gets turned On, which then brings up a Dialog.. But since I have a User Preference to enable/disable this functionality, I have to consider the case of the user possibly enabling or disabling this Preference multiple times, back-and-forth. This is why I would like to achieve my goal by programmatically enabling/disabling the `BroadcastReceiver` immediately upon the Preference being changed, within `onSharedPreferenceChanged` itself, directly.. So I simply need assistance fixing the code I attempted in my post, if possible?